# create dotted circle border in dart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Need to create dotted circle border. Tried dotted border with radius property but still it
not filling up like complete dotted circle with the text. Please help to create dotted border like the image.
Thanks

```
Center(
            child: Text('Received'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Center(
            child: Text('Shipped'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Center(
            child: DottedBorder(
              dashPattern: const [8, 4],
              strokeWidth: 1,
              color: mainColor,
              radius: Radius.circular(20),
              child: SizedBox(),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
          Center(
            child: Text('Delivered'),
          )
```

[image: Design]

Comment: try this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border)

Answer (score 4):

You can define the type by using BorderType.Circle to get a circular border

```
DottedBorder(
            borderType: BorderType.Circle,
            dashPattern: const [5, 10],
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 50,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle),
            )),
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

You can use dotted_border package

```
    return DottedBorder(
    borderType: BorderType.RRect,
    radius: Radius.circular(12),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(6),
    child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
    child: Container(
      height: 200,
      width: 120,
      color: Colors.amber,
       ),
     ),
    );
```